# Rails 3 - link for delete item

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink, controller

I have list of images and for every image I have link for deleting. That link looks this:

```
<%= link_to 'delete image', {:controller => 'shops', :action => 'delimg', :imgid => u.id}, :confirm => 'Really?' %>
```

def logo
    puts params[:imgid]
    ...
  end

And I am getting an error **Couldn't find Shop with ID=logo** and **app/controllers/shops_controller.rb:17:in `show'** - I tried to add **puts 'IN SHOW** and it really looks, that after click on that link is called method **show**. I have no idea, how it is possible...

Could someone help me, please, where is the problem?

Comment: How do your routes look like? Is 'delimg' a member route of the shops resources?

Comment: In routes.rb I have  resources :shops
  get 'shops/index'
  get 'shops/logo'

. The action 'delimg' is in class 'shops_controller'

Comment: have you defined route for delimg? if not then define it in routes.rb

Comment: and where is 'shops/delimg' as u have write in the link action=> delimg?? do u have method delimg in the controller shops??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably how I would have done it:

```
#routes.rb
resources :shops do
  delete :delimg, :on => :member
end
```

By adding that, there will be a defined route to the delimg action mapped to the delete method. And that makes it possible to do the following in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'delete image', delimg_shop_path(u.id), :method => :delete %>
```

delimg_shop_path is a path helper that exists because of what was added in the routes.rb

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I would like to ask you - why I need to add that information to routes.rb (about resources) and why not enough just add name of action to controller and "get(post) controller/action"? That should be work, or?

Comment: That only works if you have the dynamic route match ':controller(/:action(/:id))' and that is really bad practice to use. You should define all routing in the routes.rb to make sure you know all the routes that work.

Answer (score 0):

you are displaying params[:ingid] in the logo method but in the link to action u have specified delimg??
modiefy your link to as

`<%= link_to 'delete image', {:controller => 'shops', :action => 'logo', :imgid => u.id}, :confirm => 'Really?' %>`

then it will work